# Create a SVG object with a arrow line Highcharts

Tags: svg, highcharts

I need to draw a arrow line pointing to a particular point in my highcharts.
I was able to get the line drawn but not sure how to have a arrow before that being displayed.

Here is my fiddle and code.

http://jsfiddle.net/48kyq3wq/1/

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function(data) {

  var callout = function(chart) {
    $('.cO').remove();
    var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
      yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
      point = chart.series[0].data[100],
      lineXLength = 100,
      lineYLength = -50;
    chart.renderer.path(['M', xAxis.toPixels(point.x), yAxis.toPixels(point.y), 'L', xAxis.toPixels(point.x) + lineXLength, yAxis.toPixels(point.y) + lineYLength,]).attr({
      'stroke-width': 5,
      stroke: 'red',
      zIndex: 0
    }).addClass('C0').add();

    chart.renderer.label('Custom label', xAxis.toPixels(point.x) + lineXLength, yAxis.toPixels(point.y) + lineYLength - 22, 'rect')
      .css({
        color: '#FFFFFF'
      })
      .attr({
        fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
        padding: 8,
        r: 5,
        width: 100,
        height: 30,
        zIndex: 6
      }).addClass('cO')
      .add();
  };


  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          callout(this);
        },
        redraw: function() {
          callout(this);
        }
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      data: data
    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an arrow and rotate it depending on the position of point and the label.

1. Create a path which connects the label and the point

   ```
   const x0 = label.x;
   const y0 = label.y + label.height / 2;
   const x1 = x;
   const y1 = y;

   const path = chart.renderer.path([
     'M', label.x, label.y + label.height / 2,
     'L', x, y,
   ]).attr({
     'stroke-width': 1,
     stroke: 'black',
     zIndex: 6
   }).add()
   ```
2. Create a method for rotating points. It will rotate the point around the top point of the arrow

   ```
   function rotatePoint(c, angle, p) {
     const sin = Math.sin(angle);
     const cos = Math.cos(angle);
     const x = p[0] - c[0];
     const y = p[1] - c[1];

     const nx = x * cos - y * sin;
     const ny = x * sin + y * cos;

     return [nx + c[0], ny + c[1]];
   }
   ```
3. Create an arrow, find the angle between the label and the point and rotate the arrow according to the angle.

   ```
   const array = [[x1 - 5, y1 - 15], [x1 + 5, y1 - 15], [x1, y1], [x1 - 5, y1- 15]]
   const angle = Math.atan2(y0 - y1, x0 - x1) + 90 * Math.PI / 180;
   const ma = array.map(point => rotatePoint(array[2], angle, point));
   ```
4. Render the arrow

   ```
   const arrow = chart.renderer.path({
     fill: 'black',
     zIndex: 6,
     d: ['M', ma[0].join(' '), 'L', ma[1].join(' '), ma[2].join(' '), ma[3].join(' ')].join(' ')
   }).add()
   ```

You should also consider cases when the point is on the right of the label and the top of the label - rotation and calculation of the angle stay the same but connecting the point with the label needs to be adjusted.

#### Live example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/savpscya/

[image: arrowed label]